# problems with facebook callback in omniauth

Tags: ruby, facebook, callback, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook in my app, I am not very sure but I guess I'm having a problem with the routes, since it does not reach the method where I redirect.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
match '/auth/facebook/callback' => 'user#create'
resources :users

        require 'omniauth'
    class UserController < ApplicationController

      def create
        if User.exists?(:condition => ["email=?",auth_hash["info"]["email"]])
          self.current_user = User.find(:all,:condition => ["email=?",auth_hash["info"]["email"]])
        else
          self.current_user = User.new(:email => auth_hash["info"]["email"])
        redirect_to 'deals#generate_ticket'
      end
        end

def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end 


Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      :scope => 'email'
    end
```

Maybe I'm missing something in the routes or maybe i have not installed correctly the gem. I will be sincerely greatful for every help.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, but: Did you add to your gemfile the following?:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Also you are using: require 'omniauth', maybe it should be 'omniauth-facebook'. But I suggest you to add the gems to your gemfile instead of using require.

Regards..
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have tried it and I'm still in the same situation. When it initiates the callbitack phase, an error occurs:       TypeError             
can't convert Pathname into String.

I have no clue about what could be the reason of the error, any idea?